# Error while applying patch on AOSP

Tags: git, android-source

When I am trying to apply patch on AOSP I am getting following error:

> error: unable to open object pack directory: .git/objects/pack: Not a
>   directory error: unable to open object pack directory:
>   .git/objects/pack: Not a directory error: unable to open object pack
>   directory: .git/objects/pack: Not a directory fatal: failed to read
>   object 9bdcff7bdf72dd69f43c2b3d6fc20474130008c0: Not a directory
>   Error! Base version commit 9bdcff7bdf72dd69f43c2b3d6fc20474130008c0
>   doesn't exist in git
>   /home/usr/Android_Src/android/android/packages/apps/Dialer. Stop

But I am able to view `.git/objects/pack` directory. I am confused why it is saying that:

> .git/objects/pack: Not a directory.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Was it a patch file or a commit? What commands did you run?

Comment: I was running c_patch command for nxp processors. Earlier it was running fine. After I copied the code to other machine, it started throwing error.

Comment: How did you copied? Via `git clone` or some other method?

Comment: repo sync as given in "https://source.android.com/source/downloading"

Comment: Ok.. it  seems some files were missing in the ASOP source code. Hence, I cloned it again and it's working perfectly now.